# TypeError: tf.dataSync is not a function

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I'm getting the error as displayed in the title.

A week ago this same piece of code was working fine!

I haven't changed anything (well, at least that I've noticed).

I'm importing API 2.0.0.

Thank you in advance :)

Code:

```
async function makePrediction(x) {
    
    // variables
    var tensor = tf.tensor([x]);

    // there is a problem with the conversion
    // using an execute method, feeding the inputs as a dictionary and the outputs names as a list
    let outputs = await model.execute({
        'xTensor': tensor
    },
        ['accuracy/modelPrediction:0']);

    // get value from tensor
    // since we only have one value, we can get it straight away
    const result = tf.dataSync()[0];
    console.log(result);

    // cleanup
    outputs.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all: `dataSync` is a method of a `tf.tensor`. what you want to do is to call `outputs.dataSync()` if output is a tensor

Comment: That, indeed, solved my problem. Although I'll still say it's weird, since last week I used that code and I was able to get a prediction from the model. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You most likely changed something